# Change the cursor shape inside mouseDown / mouseUp functions in SVG

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a draggable svg. I'd like to change the cursor look in reaction on mouse events.

```
svg.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
svg.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(e) {
    // cursor = 'move'
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
    // cursor = 'regular'
}
```

I tried to call `svg.setAttribute('cursor', 'move')` with no luck though.

I wonder if there's a way to change svg attributes (such as cursor look) in a dynamic manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) rules from javascript:

```
function onMouseDown(e) {
  this.style.cursor = 'move'
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
  this.style.cursor = 'pointer'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With those event listeners (and some helper CSS classes) you can achieve your desired result:

```js
const svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

svg.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
svg.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(e) {
    svg.classList.add('moving');
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
    svg.classList.remove('moving');
}
```

```css
.moveable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.moveable.moving {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" class="moveable">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Despite everything works perfectly in your answer, I chosen another one because it introduced `svg.style` attribute to me (the way I adopted the feature in my code) in addition to prove the possibility of the whole deal.